# passing two query variables to jquery return data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I want to send two query variables and want to send those values to jquery ajax data value.Now I get nothing in ajax page.If I use one query statement and passed one value I get some output

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'get-details',
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'id='+user_id,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data,data1,textStatus, jqXHR){ //want to add data1
    var id = data.id;
    var alt=data1.column; 
    alert(data1.column);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

  },
});  

public function getDetails(Request $request)
{
  $request_data = $request->all();
$user_id = $request_data['id'];
$user_data =DB::table('travel_request')
        ->join('department', 'travel_request.department_id', '=', 'department.id')
         ->select('travel_request.*')->where('travel_request.id',$user_id)->first();  
$req=DB::table('traveling_details')->select('traveling_details.*')->get(); //has multiple value
return response()->json($user_data,$req);
}
```

Comment: make sure you have configure your route properly. because in ajax you function name is get-details and in controller you have defined getDetails,
so your route should be configure for this like `Route::get('get-details','YourController@getDetails');`

Comment: what error you are getting  ?  also try echo $user_id = $request_data['id'];  if you are getting it.

Comment: yes i got return value id if I passed one query in my controller and (data,textStatus, jqXHR)) is in success data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this if it works

```
$data['user_data'] = DB::table('travel_request')
        ->join('department', 'travel_request.department_id', '=', 'department.id')
         ->select('travel_request.*')->where('travel_request.id',$user_id)->first();  

$data['req'] = DB::table('traveling_details')->select('traveling_details.*')->get(); //has multiple value

return response()->json($data);
```

And You ajax function in view file should be like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'get-details',
  type: 'GET',
  data: 'id='+user_id,
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data){ //want to add data1

      var user_data = data.user_data;
      var req = data.req;

      console.log(user_data);
      console.log(req);

      // to access the column of the user_data
      var YourVariableName = user_data.ColumnNameHere;

  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

  },
});
```

Comment: how to get this in ajax page

Comment: public/get-details?id=5  500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: working as to told  
how to traverse req val I got like this id
:
1
ticket_required
:
1
to_date
:
"2016-12-31"
travel_request_id
:
5
travel_type_id
:
1
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
country_id
:
2
destination
:
"sdfdfsd"
from_date
:
"2016-12-07"
id
:
2
ticket_required
:
1
to_date
:
"2017-01-31"
travel_request_id
:
6
travel_type_id
:
1
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
country_id
:
2
destination
:
"dfgdfg"
from_date
:
"2016-12-31"
id
:
3
ticket_required
:
1
to_date
:
"2017-02-28"
travel_request_id
:
5
travel_type_id
:
2

Comment: try alert(req.id), you will get it . same like others.  req.to_date  etc